# How can I use multiple monitors on Ubuntu linux running as a VirtualBox guest OS

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, multiple-monitors

I've set up my VirtualBox VM to have two monitors as shown below

[image]

When I start the guest OS (Ubuntu 19.10) in full screen model I use the File menu to assign Virtual Screen 2 to Host Screen 3, but nothing ever appears on Host Screen 3.  Ubuntu linux display settings only shows one display.

The missing piece seems to be getting the Ubuntu guest OS to recognize the second virtual display.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by installing VMWare Player.  It supports multiple monitors in a simple, intuitive way, and it works.

Comment: Is this really an answer since this is suggesting another workaround other than using VirtualBox?

Answer (score 0):

In Display -> Screen choose "VboxVGA" as the graphics controller, worked for me.

Edit 30min. later: After endless of tests (because of stutering and low perfomance), I removed virtualbox and installed vmware.

Comment: I had to do the same thing.  VirtualBox crashed 3 times in one afternoon.